# How to deal with extremely low variance features

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, variance, descriptive-statistics, unsupervised-learning

I am currently in the process of doing feature extraction for cluster analysis. Some of my features have an extremely low variance, resulting in a very "narrow" distribution, meaning that most observations center around one point. I am worried that this kind of distribution is very unsuited for clustering because it causes strange patterns when plotted against other features (including ones that are similarly distributed).

I have tried removing outliers, but even then the distribution changes very little, and I lose a lot of data. In fact, I would prefer not to remove any outliers. Is there a kind of transformation I could perform that might be suitable? To illustrate my problem I have plotted the data, with different levels of outlier removal (none to high). In my opinion it becomes especially problematic for clustering when I have 2 or more of these types of features in my dataset.

Is there a clustering algorithm that can deal with these kinds of distributions?
Is there a transformation/scaling method to help me deal with this?

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc6Vl.png) you can see the histograms of each feature, as well as a scatterplot. The top panel is the uncut data, the second panel I removed 5th and 95th percentile etc.

tl;dr I have very low-variance features that I want to use for clustering. I want to know if there is a way to transform them, or a suitable clustering algorithm to use.

Comment: why don't you treat them as numbers on a line and cluster them by defining different intervals?

Comment: Have you tried normalizing the features, this makes the scales of the  features similar.

Comment: @xi45 thanks for answering! That's something I have already considered actually. However, I want to find "natural" clusters, rather than arbitrarily cutting up the distribution into quantiles.

Comment: @spdrnl yes. Normalization does not help the issue. Actually what you see in the picture I posted, is already normalized

Comment: @xi45 Quick follow up question: Do you think the methodology you suggested would also be appropriate when there are multiple features? 
Thanks in advance!